# org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n

Tags: json, api, rest

What I am doing :
REST API call to create a page with table in confluence.

- When I use POSTMAN and execute the given code in JSON, it creates a page with table.  `{ "title": "Title", "type": "page", "space":{ "key": "spacekeyhere" }, "status": "current",  "ancestors": [{ "id": "parentid" }], "body": { "storage":{   "value": "<table data-layout=\"default\"><colgroup><col style=\"width: 226.67px;\" /><col style=\"width: 226.67px;\" /><col style=\"width: 226.67px;\" /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th><p><strong>Col1</strong></p></th><th><p><strong>Col2</strong></p></th><th><p /></th></tr><tr><td><p>AAA</p></td><td><p>A</p></td><td><p /></td></tr><tr><td><p>testing 2</p></td><td><p>B</p></td><td><p /></td></tr></tbody></table>", "representation": "storage" },}}`

But when I use the same code in NODE.js ( visual studio) ( content-type is still json there) , it throws an error : Response: 500 Internal Server Error
{"statusCode":500,"message":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.limitrequest.jersey.LimitingRequestFilter$1@2eb4e939; line: 11, column: 39]"}

**After removing the CSS in the code .**

was changed to
 , it worked
But why it is causing issues with this format as it should not make any difference right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found few minutes ago how to solved it.
in your string you should replace the " by '
so basicly in your body section:

```
<table data-layout=\"default\"><colgroup><col style=\"width: 226.67px;\" /><col style=\"width: 226.67px;\" /><col style=\"width: 226.67px;\" /></colgroup>
```

become :

```
<table data-layout='default'><colgroup><col style='width: 226.67px;' /><col style='width: 226.67px;' /><col style='width: 226.67px;' /></colgroup>
```

And I also think it will be needed for every kind of macro that you may call as chart, or link that you may insert.

Hope it's may help you or other people.